# Should Mozilla cache files ever contain PHP eval statements?

Tags: firefox, wireshark, cache

I am concerned about a breach on my network and starting greping my system for common PHP and Perl functions.

I found eval statements in both `home/user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/xxxxxx.default-release/cache2/entries` and in Wireshark `pcapng` files I have run while accessing my LAN and the internet.

Is it normal for cache and pcapng files to contain eval statements?

**Edit: Here is the grep output**

```
$sudo grep -Rn "eval *(" /home

grep: warning: /home/admin-user/.local/share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v0: recursive directory loop
grep: /home/admin-user/.mozilla/firefox/r5ltgfpz.default-release/lock: No such file or directory
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/587E705F8250A3BAD1725FFDC0308BE13FC9C249 matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/56C137F3ED4BD95ED5365B85D979D27E45A3C06B matches
/home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/0C9E9204B87889165E9EF9B84C7C50ADCB85DEF4:5103:function Kjj(a,b){a.b=eval(b);a.a=a.b.length;a.e.e=Ckh(eYi,VHj,1,0,3,1);Ajj(a,Pjj(a));zjj(a,Pjj(a));if(a.k!=7){throw new qhj('Expecting version 7 from server, got '+a.k+'.')}if(((a.j|3)^3)!=0){throw new qhj('Got an unknown flag from server: '+a.j)}a.d=a.b[--a.a]}

Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/C0C1113F6EE7EC8F9FF4A8CEB4705760115AB1D8 matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/FD1D3EF0DAB5FB5F5AEB46B86EEE1CA545CA5AE7 matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/CDB782750F3F83552C72C19162902F70F96C1630 matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/365B418963D1670AC92B9E2EA38B97E1B6AE87BB matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/8E7F89CB9F59D6708DE57A98C6797AACF9514AA3 matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/947BAE73C678232D86FC86AD72CF19B5FD27DFBC matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/FC62728FEED8B45EE4FC3565B5F4CD117DBEF695 matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/2483BD620420574E867403E19203A4FDD311A014 matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/DB29AC2E40BE65FF0ECDB50A304727F1C40F037D matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/75DFE1E5FD6A4F82B4C84951482B6BB0DDFAE633 matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/46759B453E394486BB835EF50C93ECE894CD8839 matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/379C840BF0F9586EB8A994393667A9E3DD27E7EA matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/7B15FC961E85FA18FC7DB39B8356FD3D6847EBE6 matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/A946D1D076B90EBB0D84636A225E961B2CEC9175 matches
Binary file /home/depreciated-user/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/cache2/entries/63F7CA4B34EE77F607DF43332730EC89926E0E60 matches

grep: /home/depreciated-user/.mozilla/firefox/3agw7l97.default-release/lock: No such file or directory
```

I'm  not a programmer, but it sure looks like obfuscated code to me. FYI: this system was just installed and the only websites visited after installation were for banking and technical forums.

Comment: Raw PHP and Perl and other code mean nothing on your local network if you are on a client machine and browsing. That is just the content of a web page and if you visit a page that has PHP or Perl code for content — like a Q&A site like Stack Overflow — then that is that. The only time you *might* be concerned is if you are running a web server and see your logs contain requests like that; it might be a hacking attempt. NewsFlash™: Any and all websites online are probed by bot scripts for common vulnerabilities. Don’t worry about it… Unless your server and site are massively out of date.

Comment: I know for a fact my workstations and OPN firewall have been compromised. If I connect any of my four workstations to the internet, or even just boot my dedicated machine for OPNsense, all five try to send data to a whole range of IP addresses that include websites I have never visited (I did whois and reverse ip on most of the offenders), DOD, Army, NASA, GROOT, BROOT, RIPE Coordination, APNIC, Amazon dogfish routing, and on and on. These ips never show up in the workstation fw logs, only on OPN.

Comment: Just to make sure, disabled ntpd service on OPN and a test workstation. Still happens. At one point pftop logged almost 70,000 States, the only thing open was one browser tab for OPN webgui. I'm trying to figure out how my machines became compromised and how to stop it.

Comment: I found this on test workstation https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653730/random-ssh-agent-generates-on-boot-in-tmp-directory-even-with-networking-disable

Comment: @emptysocket: Regarding the DOD/RIPE/NASA contacts, I've added an update at the bottom of the answer about those as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### New answer

You said in the comments that you actually don't know whether this is a PHP eval() in the first place. The thing is, PHP is not the only language that has an eval() – JavaScript has an eval() function as well.

Now while having PHP code in your browser's cache is mildly unusual, having JavaScript code in your browser's cache is *completely normal,* and yes that even includes code which calls eval().

(For example, a website could use JavaScript to dynamically refresh some data (such as the "installed packages" table), by receiving updates in JSON. While modern JavaScript has a dedicated JSON-parsing function, for a long time it did not – instead, to parse a JSON string you would eval() it.)

This does not mean the code was generated by a process on your computer. It was *received* by the browser, but that's how all websites work, and it's pretty much the purpose of a browser's cache.

> I'm not a programmer, but it sure looks like obfuscated code to me

If a website uses obfuscated code, that's really *their* business.

But nowadays, many websites use obfuscators called *minifiers,* where the goal is simply to compress the JavaScript code as much as possible (e.g. shortening all variables to 1- or 2-letter) so that it could be downloaded faster by visitors, with obfuscation as a secondary effect. You will see this on just about every larger website you visit.

(Some obfuscators and minifiers indeed use eval() to reconstruct parts of the original code.)

#### Original answer

If you open a webpage that literally contains an unprocessed PHP statement, then yes, it'll of course show up on the network and in the page that you see, and therefore also in the cache.

For example, if I type this in the answer form:

```
<?php eval("echo 'Hello!';") ?>
```

now your cache for superuser.com has a PHP eval statement in it.

However, your browser doesn't process PHP statements; it either treats them as regular text or as a weird nonstandard XML processing directive. If they were supposed to be interpreted, that'd have happened on the server – you wouldn't be supposed to receive them.

The real question is whether the *website* should have had that statement in the page you visited. It could very well might be something that was added maliciously, it might have been added to a completely wrong file, or it might be just ordinary text in that page.

For example, if an attacker uploads a PHP script to a site that *doesn't use PHP,* then it will not be interpreted – you'll get the source code as text. (Some attacks involve putting PHP code in e.g. the GIF or JPEG comment field, uploading it as a .gif and tricking the server into interpreting it as PHP.)

But as another example, if the website has been unmaintained for years and uses legacy `<?` short open tags, modern PHP won't look at those anymore and you'll see the raw PHP statements in your browser instead. This isn't anything malicious, just a sign of the site being incompatible with the webserver.

#### Answer to comments

> even just boot my dedicated machine for OPNsense, all five try to send data to a whole range of IP addresses that include websites I have never visited (I did whois and reverse ip on most of the offenders), DOD, Army, NASA, GROOT, BROOT, RIPE Coordination, APNIC, Amazon dogfish routing, and on and on. These ips never show up in the workstation fw logs, only on OPN.

All of those sound completely normal when put together.

Your OPNsense system is running Unbound as a DNS resolver. It doesn't just forward the requests to another server – it acts like a *full* resolver (like the ones run by ISPs), chasing DNS delegations from the root down to the TLDs and the actual domains, by itself.

First, this means that each DNS request (made either by your workstations or by OPNsense internal processes) will result in more than one DNS query, as the resolver doesn't immediately know where to ask the final question, it has to find out by following delegations.

This process always starts at the *DNS root,* and many of the organizations in your list are simply hosting instances of the nameservers for the root zone – it is normal for a DNS resolver to be probing them on startup. Yes, DoD indeed hosts one, and so does the US Army, and so does RIPE, and NASA. (And e.g. "GROOT" is a dedicated address range for the 'G' nameserver.) You can see the full list at http://root-servers.org.

The same then applies for the nameservers of the TLD, and then of the actual domain being resolved. Often, even the domain's nameservers will seemingly have nothing to do with the domain. For example, Amazon (known for AWS cloud computing) provides the "Route53" DNS hosting service that many websites use.

So whenever OPNsense starts up and contacts `opnsense.org` to check for available updates, the DNS resolver has to contact that domain's authoritative DNS servers (e.g. `ns3.openprovider.eu`) – which indeed are hosted at Amazon. (I'm not sure whether openprovider uses Route53 or Cloudfront or EC2, but it's all the same AWS in the end.)

It is never enough to look at only the IP addresses: you have to look at the actual traffic that's being sent to those addresses (or received). As the bare minimum, look also at the protocols and ports – I'm fairly sure these are UDP packets to dstport 53, i.e. DNS queries.

Comment: What I found was obfuscated php with an eval statement matching the same version number of Charon running on said workstation.

Comment: What is Charon?

Comment: It is used for VPN connections, but not by me. I added a comment to the question with link to more weirdness on the same workstation.

Comment: Oh, so the strongSwan component? I'm mostly thinking you're just seeing a regular part of the OPNsense web interface, then. Do you know for sure it's a PHP eval() and not a JavaScript eval()?

Comment: No I don't know anything for sure. It just matched a grep for "eval (*". Interestingly enough I tried to remove strongswan-Charon via apt and it will not allow it unless I first install an alternate VPN package.

Comment: The eval statements were found on workstation, not OPN.

Comment: Of course they were – your workstation had to receive stuff in order to _display_ the OPN web interface. Just like it has to receive a bunch of JavaScript from superuser.com so that it could show this web page here. That doesn't mean it was *generated* by any process on the workstation; it was merely *cached* on the workstation (that's what the cache is for!) but still originated from the website in question.

Comment: I'm certainly not trying to annoy anyone, just try to track down a compromise that I know exists. But as I search my systems I don't always have the technical skill to know what processes should or shouldn't be there.

Comment: This answer is correct, but this question should not have been answered. It is a very strong candidate for an “[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319)” question; one where the core question is not being asked and is only coming out in panicky comments. If you ask me, these are not infected workstations but rather a very extreme misinterpretation of basic traffic.

Comment: Well I feel that you are wrong. I needed to know whether or cache files could contain eval statements. So I asked the question. Now I know that they can. Just because there are extenuating circumstances that made me ask the question doesn't make it irrelevant. My problem can't be addressed in one post. And my comments are not panicky, they represent me trying to troubleshoot a serious problem. They are the process of elimination.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: Someone has to provide the right interpretation though. Or do you want to stuff the answer in a comment and pretend it's not an answer?